# Finding (or rather expanding) the product $(5-xy)(3+xy)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, products

Given the product $(5-xy)(3+xy)$

I tried the following,

As we know, $(x+a)(x+b)=x^2+(a+b)x+ab$

Here $x$ is $xy$. But $xy$ has two signs$-$ and $+$.

How do I solve this.

Comment: $5 - xy = 5 + (-xy)$. But don't just memorize a rule - this is just applying the distributive property a few times.

Comment: Is there any need of applying result ...It's better to use distributive property

Comment: You cannot use the given formula since the product isn't of that form. Though we have that
$$(x+a)(-x+b) = -x^2+(b-a)x+ab $$
which you can apply to the given problem. Although, I would strongly advise to not just memorize formulas but understand how they are derived.

Comment: One way would be to rewrite as $-(xy-5)(xy+3)$ which fits the pattern you know - but really you just need to get used to this kind of expression by doing some examples - in the end it won't matter how you get to the answer.

Comment: It's okay to put a not-too-large formula in the title. Think of how many similar questions are asked here (in the Related column to the right). If the title is "finding the product", there is no way of telling them apart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \begin {align*} (5 - xy)(3 + xy) &= 5 \cdot 3 + 3 \cdot (-xy) + 5 \cdot (xy) + (-xy) \cdot (xy) \\&= 15 - 3xy + 5xy - (xy)^2 \\&= 15 + 2xy - x^2y^2. \end {align*} $$Hope that makes sense!

Comment: But, we have to use a formula.

Comment: As @T. Bongers said, this is a formula applied differently than how you might think. Learn the property, not a formula. The "FOIL formula" that you are thinking of is exactly this, but remember that the *concept* is just the distributive property. Please realize that this is a math concept, not the application of a formula. The formula comes from the concept of distribution.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad you *understood* the concept. :)

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the [**FOIL** method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOIL_method).

You multiply the **FIRST** terms: $5 \cdot 3 = 15$
You multiply the **OUTER** terms: $5 \cdot xy = 5xy$
You multiply the **INNER** terms: $-xy \cdot 3 = -3xy$
You multiply the **LAST** terms: $xy \cdot -xy = -x^2y^2$

You add them all together: $15 + 5xy + -3xy + -x^2y^2 = 15 + 2xy - x^2y^2$

And you're done.

Comment: We have to use a formula to solve this as this is a chapter of expansions.

Comment: @Abhishekstudent the FOIL method is the standard way of solving this problem. I can almost guarantee you that this is the 'formula' your teacher has in mind. (Go ask your teacher for clarification?)